# How to get OpsGenie alerts for Firebase Crashlytics Issues

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, opsgenie

In my org, we are trying to setup OpsGenie alerts for Firebase Crashlytics issues.

For any fatal issues at project like ANRs, Crashes, we are trying to receive OG alerts.

As per the doc , https://support.atlassian.com/opsgenie/docs/integrate-opsgenie-with-crashlytics/

Direct Integration is not supported now it seems.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

I tried

Firebase Project -> Settings -> Integrations

And try to explore OpsGenie option in that. It's not there.